# Java library suggestions for implementing a custom web server

Tags: webserver, web-services, java

I would like to create a web server that will serve/accept json files through REST. The JSON files being served will come from a database query and format the results into JSON.
Any suggestions for a good java library. I have tried using Apache HTTPComponents.
While maybe I can just create a servlet but I am not really allowed to install a servlet container in the server machine.

EDIT:
I was just thinking to create the program where I can just simply issue a simple java -jar Application.jar and everything is already started and functional. The application will listen on a certain port of the machine and respond to some requests from browser and/or another java program. Looks like Jetty will help me do it. As I have said, I have implemented something using HTTPComponents and I'm just simply parsing the URL from the requests and do something in the server based on the parsed URL.

Comment: If you're not allowed to install a servlet container I'm not sure they'll be happy with you installing a custom web server.  This sounds like a job best suited for a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of the venerable [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).  It's small and straightforward. It's *technically* a servlet container (it's more thought of an embedded HTTP server), but you can embed it within your own app.  It also supports Java REST libraries such as [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is a fantastic web services library.  It has built-in support for REST, but I haven't tried that particular feature myself.  CXF uses Jetty by default, but it's designed to be easily adaptable to Tomcat or other servlet containers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at:

- JBoss [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)
- [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)

What I like about them:

- Both of you can be run embedded (as jar).
- They also both support an "asynchronous event-driven"/NIO architecture. Jetty has [continuations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations) for this. NIO is the new way of handling IO and has the ability to scale  better.

Comment: Do you thing Jetty will be a good choice? and maybe use RESTlet to implement the RESTful web service?

Comment: I think you could both implement REST on Jetty and Netty. My first choice would be netty to be honest. I have been playing a lot with it lately and I like it a lot. Small footprint and really fast. But Also Jetty is a really good package. A lot of big company's use Jetty. Google's java app engine runs on Jetty for example. Implementing REST interface is for most part I think about discipline. Documenting your API well. But Netty/Jetty support GET/PUT/POST/DELETE semantics(easily) which are neccesary to implement REST API/interface.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Restlet: 
[Restlet Tutorial](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/) project

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all the overhead and complexity of a web server?  It sounds like all you really need is a socket listener.